# What is the lifecycle of an AccessibilityNodeInfo?

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I am working on an Android app that includes an Accessibility Service to allow users to create 'macros' that can quickly and automatically perform tasks they do frequently with third party apps they already use (instead of having to interact with some talkback service where they wait for things to be listed and then have to speak each thing they want it to do in a very slow process over and over). My problem is that I cannot seem to find detailed documentation about the life cycle of AccessibilityNodeInfo objects. For example, if a macro is set up as "open this app and click the 'Go' button, then list all results" I may need to wait and collect incremental updates in the app, as results can come in across multiple WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED events, each of which only contain a subset of the total results list the app is building. I can grab the elements I want with things like findViewById, but is keeping them around across multiple events is a bad idea, since the android os can at any time invalidate / change them? I am wondering if there are any docs/examples out there I have missed that make more clear how best to interact accessibilityNodeInfo objects, and how / if I can cache or collect them over time to get a more full and consistent picture of what is in the app's layout.

I have looked at other posts about accessibilitynodeinfo such as ([Android AccessibilityNodeInfo refresh() and recycle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921893/android-accessibilitynodeinfo-refresh-and-recycle)) but this still does not answer questions such as when a node becomes invalid or what happens if I do not recycle a node and try to use it later (especially if the element has been removed by the app). The questions I am looking to answer are of the sort in the code below:

```java
//for caching nodes... bad idea?
HashMap<String,AccessibilityNodeInfo> cachedNodes = new HashMap<>();

//gets fired for lots of reasons, can contain arbitrary subsets of the total app layout hierarchy (appears upper bounded by what is visible on the screen)
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    // my accessibility service is listening to all event types
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
    //sometimes the node is just totally null... why??
    if(nodeInfo != null){
        //what is this really doing? Why is this node sometimes different from traversing up the hierarchy with getParent() manually?
        rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
        if(rootNode == null) {
            rootNode = nodeInfo;
            AccessibilityNodeInfo parent = nodeInfo.getParent();
            while(parent != null){
                rootNode = parent;
                parent = rootNode.getParent();
            }
        }
        //It appears this method returns all matches in the event hierarchy regardless of which node you call it on?
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodesOfInterest = rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("package.name/id_of_nodes_i_want");
        for(AccessibilityNodeInfo node: nodesOfInterest){
            //my accessibility service is set up to be able to get view ids and retrieve window content, but view ids are not unique
            // may have to compose an ID based on the view type lineage of the node?
            if(!cachedNodes.containsKey(getUniqueID(node)){
                cachedNodes.put(getUniqueID(node),node);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AccessibilityNodeInfo or AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat` (For backword compatibility)
are not the Views.

When you open any of screen of phone its called Window's content which is presented as a tree of accessibility node infos.

Sometimes you get `AccessibilityNodeInfo` as null, but after refreshing, you can gets the value of that particular node.

```
accessibilityNodeInfo.refresh();
```

Refreshes this info with the latest state of the view it represents.

You can visit this to get more Info.[Accessibility Node Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html)

Comment: but if I call refresh() on a null reference, won't that throw an error?

Comment: You have to refresh the parent node, instead of that particular node.